# how to grab text in event onclick

Tags: javascript, php, dom, curl, simple-html-dom

hy all help me pleass..
I have quetions, how to grab text in event onlcik suing simple html dom for example :

I have see in website like this

```html
<a id="inquiry-agent-phone" class="tooltiped-links" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" onclick="scigineer_func('call');inquiryAgentPhoneLeads('xxx', 'xxx', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxx')">+62-821-22...</a>
```

I do not know what the function of the applied
and I want grab  full text phone number
Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear ... please be clear in what you want so that we could help you out ....... please be specific

Comment: I had no idea you could execute code in a question.

Comment: hy Vicky I' so sorry if my Quetion not clear. because I'm confused. ok my problem is.. first I want grab text in event onclick. logical is if I'm grab text he is to half text and I want full text not to be half text  thanks

Comment: It's not clear what language you're using. Or what you have against spell-check.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script,

$html = str_get_html('*URL HTML SCRIPT*');

echo $html->find('a[id=inquiry-agent-phone]', 0)->plaintext;

Comment: Akilan thanks for your answer but I want full text not just '+62-821-22... but like this '+62-821-22000827371

Comment: you can't trigger the java script event using php dom parser. you have to try some jquery parser

Comment: already but not success still half text this my code : <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#inquiry-agent-phone').("click");
});
</script>

Comment: not like this. I mean u have to use jquery html parser. u can get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i don't know whether i understood what your requirement is but if i am not wrong then here is a way that you can do it using jquery

HTML

```
<a id="inquiry-agent-phone1" class="tooltiped-links" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">+62-821-22 55 33 555 888</a>
<br/><br/>
<a id="inquiry-agent-phone2" class="tooltiped-links" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">+62-821-22 55 33 555 999</a>
<br/><br/>
<a id="inquiry-agent-phone3" class="tooltiped-links" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">+62-821-22 55 33 555 000</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tooltiped-links").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        var data=$("#"+id).text();
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle for your reference ------> [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nephilim11/82py19ms/1/)